# Some questions about Room and Paging Library

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am trying to set up all my lists with [Room Persistance Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) and [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) but I am facing some problems when implementing `PagedListAdapter`.

**Question 1**

I don't want to write any `if`, `when`... conditions in the `onBindViewHolder` so the scrolling is completely fluid. I have a model with its attributes. As an example, I want to set the visibility of a `view` that it is inside the layout (like a `TextView`) depending on a `Boolean` of the model, but I don't want to use an if. What would be the correct way of achieving that?

Should I create an `Int` attribute in the model which has the `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE`? But then the model can get very complex with lots of attributes and all of them are on all the model objects of the `Room` database.

Should I create another model which only has the attributes needed for the adapter UI? But then every time the real model is modified, I also have to modify the adapter model in order to see changes on the UI. And I think that's not good at all.

Do you know if there is somewhere where I can do this **asynchronously** in `PagedListAdapter`?

**Question 2**

I need to use functions like `getString(R.string.resource)`, which requires a `context`. I also need to use `Glide` to load an image into an `ImageView`, but it requires an `Activity context` or `Fragment context`. I tried to inject it using dagger but that's not possible. It is safe to pass that context through the constructor? Or what is the best way of doing that?
(I suppose the same problem happens implementing `RecyclerViewAdapter`)

Answer (score 0):

1. In my studied application I have table which save the current player state. This table I use in multiselect queries, so when I change this table, `Paging library`  will change my DataSource. [Example app](https://github.com/OlafStaf/EnjoyMusic/tree/deezer).
2. I use `Context` instance from `View` instance with method `View.getContext()`.